# Insufficient regional quota to satisfy request for resource: "CPUS"

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have scripts that build up and tear down clusters on Google Cloud Platform. After running these scripts several times without error, I am now unable to run the script to build up a cluster, receiving the message 'Insufficient regional quota to satisfy request for resource: "CPUS". The request requires '4.0' and is short '12.0'. The regional quota is '8.0' with '-8.0' available.' I do not see in the console any residual VMs that may have not been deleted. Is there a place where I can see my quotas and the VMs that are debited against that quota? Or perhaps there is some other resource that is being identified as "CPUS" other then VM? The line in the script that causes the error is:

```
$ gcloud container clusters create "server-cluster" \
  --machine-type "n1-standard-1" \
  --scope "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring" \
  --num-nodes "4" \
  --network $NETWORK \
  --enable-cloud-logging \
  --enable-cloud-monitoring
```

Comment: You can check the quota information using gcloud. For more information you can refer to [this link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/resource-quotas#checking_your_quota). Thanks

Answer (score 10):

You can check the quota information for a project using the [Quota](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/quotas?) page or through the following gcloud command:

```
 gcloud compute project-info describe --project myproject
```

More information can be found this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/resource-quotas#checking_your_quota).

Comment: What is the action to take if it is or is not a quota issue?

Comment: If its a quota issue you can request for [more quotas](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#requesting_additional_quota).